# BAPI or FM for Promise to pay creation?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, bapi

I'm working with Promises to pay in UDM_SUPERVISOR transaction and I need to upload Promise to pay data using BAPI/FM from an excel file.

There is a data migration template which will include all the required fields for the creation of a Customer Promise To Pay in the system.

The migration will happen using LTMC migration cockpit tool. Is there any BAPI/FM I can use for uploading Promise To Pay?

Answer (score 1):

Try function modules from `FDM_P2P_SERVICES` group which is **Promise to Pay API**.

For example UDM dashboard calls `FDM_P2P_CREATE` FM under the hood

```
ls_p2p_partner-obj_type = 'KNB1'.
ls_p2p_partner-obj_key = '0030000001CA09'.

ls_p2p_attr-fin_comp_code = "CA09".
ls_p2p_attr-fin_customer = '0030000001".
ls_p2p_attr-fin_p2p_curr = 'CAD".
ls_p2p_attr-fin_p2p_date = ls_p2p_attr-fin_p2p_due_date = "20220530".
ls_p2p_attr-fin_promised_by = 'Sandeep Phogat".
ls_p2p_attr-fin_contact_tel = "9058262323".
ls_p2p_attr-fin_contact_key = "0000000003".
APPEND ls_p2p_attr TO lt_p2p_attr.

ls_gen_inv_for_partner-obj_type = "BSEG".
ls_gen_inv_for_partner-obj_key = "CA0901000001752017001".
ls_gen_inv_for_partner-open_amount = "0.75".
ls_gen_inv_for_partner-max_p2p_amount = "0.75". 
ls_gen_inv_for_partner-assigned_p2p_amount = "0.75".
ls_gen_inv_for_partner-p2p_curr = "CAD".
ls_gen_inv_for_partner-due_date = "20170515".
ls_gen_inv_for_partner-overdue_by = "1841".
ls_gen_inv_for_partner-case_type = "CAPP".
APPEND ls_gen_inv_for_partner TO lt_gen_inv_for_partner.

CALL FUNCTION 'FDM_P2P_CREATE'
  EXPORTING
    is_p2p_partner         = ls_p2p_partner
    it_p2p_attr            = lt_p2p_attr
    it_p2p_invoice         = lt_gen_inv_for_partner
  IMPORTING
    et_p2p_created         = lt_p2p_crea_for_partner
  EXCEPTIONS
    get_number_failure     = 1
    case_interface_failure = 2.
```

If you want to upload promises from file, please check `/HEX/UPLOAD_P2P` standard report.